# json_decode in a multiple object array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON array with multiple objects and trying to use `json_decode` to make an associate array.

Sample data

```
$json='[{   
         type: "cool",
         category: "power",
         name: "Robert Downey Jr.",
         character: "Tony Stark / Iron Man",
         bio: "cool kid"
     },
       {
         type: "cool",
         category: "power",
         name: "Chris Hemsworth",
         character: "Thor",
         bio: "cool kid"
     },
     {
         type: "NotCool",
         category: "nothing",
         name: "Alexis Denisof",
         character: "The Other",
         bio: "cool kid"
     }]';
```

Here's what I am doing:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

which gives me a `NULL` result.  What am I doing wrong?

(I'm new to PHP.)

Comment: i believe you need quotes around the property names as well

Comment: This isn't valid JSON.  The keys in the objects need to be quoted, with double quotes (`"`).  Such as: `{"type": "NotCool",...}`.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. It is a valid JS object initialization, but for JSON, the keys have to be enclosed by `"` (see [http://json.org/](http://json.org/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Validate Json Try this

```
<?php
$json='[
    {
        "type": "cool",
        "category": "power",
        "name": "Robert Downey Jr.",
        "character": "Tony Stark / Iron Man",
        "bio": "cool kid"
    },
    {
        "type": "cool",
        "category": "power",
        "name": "Chris Hemsworth",
        "character": "Thor",
        "bio": "cool kid"
    },
    {
        "type": "NotCool",
        "category": "nothing",
        "name": "Alexis Denisof",
        "character": "The Other",
        "bio": "cool kid"
    }
]';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo "<pre>" ;
print_r($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON string is invalid: keys need to be quoted as well. Use [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) website, to check JSON validity.

Comment: Exactly, but you should check this out Mchl: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13FV1GaA20I

Comment: Lol. I had probably started writing something else, then changed my mind. I'm not native to English, so I rarely do mix up you're and your ;)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't valid JSON.  The keys in the objects need to be quoted, with double quotes (`"`).

It should be:

```
$json='[{
     "type": "cool",
     "category": "power",
     "name": "Robert Downey Jr.",
     "character": "Tony Stark / Iron Man",
     "bio": "cool kid"
},
{
     "type": "cool",
     "category": "power",
     "name": "Chris Hemsworth",
     "character": "Thor",
     "bio": "cool kid"
},
{
     "type": "NotCool",
     "category": "nothing",
     "name": "Alexis Denisof",
     "character": "The Other",
     "bio": "cool kid"
}]';
```

Answer (score 1):

you need double quotes around property names so it should be

JSON

```
[{   
    "type" : "cool",
    "category" : "power",
    "name" : "Robert Downey Jr.",
    "character" : "Tony Stark / Iron Man",
    "bio" : "cool kid"
}]
```

just try

PHP

```
echo json_encode(array("name" => "Tony Stark"));
```

and you will see valid json